# Pandas- How to get number of times row occurs for each corresponding value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have quite a complicated problem that I need help figuring out.

To begin, I have a dataframe:

```
 one       two     three     four      Date
comedy      a       asad      123      2013-01-18 10:00:00  
romantic    b       fas       563      2015-01-28 12:00:00
comedy      c       ewf       134      2014-01-22 09:00:00
action      a       qef       561      2013-02-18 18:00:00
action      z       adwq      1323     2016-01-23 16:00:00
...
```

I am trying to find the best way to count the number of occurrences(frequency) for each unique value in column 'one', for each week in the data column. I then want to be able to somehow compare does a higher frequency of each occurrences in each week, result in a higher or lower number for column 'four'.

My desired output is something like this, but I am open to better solutions:

```
 ones       2013-01-00  2013-01-07  2013-01-14.....    Total_frequency
 comedy         4          5           6                15
 romantic       1          2           0                3 
 action         0          0           0                0 
 ....
```

Each unique value from column 'one' is under 'ones', and their total number of occurrences for each week is under each week column. (The week columns will begin at a specified week (e.g. in the above case -> 2013-01-00).

Although, I am having trouble trying to think of the best way to relate the total frequency to column four across the dataframe.

If anyone has any idea of the best way I could go about doing this, it'd be very much appreciated.

If you need anymore information please let me know.

Edit:

```
  ones       2013-01-00  2013-01-07  2013-01-14.....    Total_frequency
 comedy         4          5           6                15
 romantic       1          2           0                3 
 action       NaN          1           0                1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about `df.groupby('one')['Date'].nunique()`  OR if Just to count values for column `one` then   `df.one.value_counts()`

Comment: Please provide the desired output and if you tried something then place that in the post as well!

Comment: @momojoh1 the desired output is derived from the sample dataset provided? if so can you please explain the logic of the counts you get, i cant understand why the count of comedy starts with 4 for example.

Comment: @momojoh1 whare does it occur? in your data or the posted data? if not the later can you edit the expected output? it doesnot make any sense as of now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#changed data sample for better verify output
print (df)
        one two three  four                 Date
0    comedy   a  asad   123  2013-01-18 10:00:00
1  romantic   b   fas   563  2013-01-28 12:00:00
2    comedy   c   ewf   134  2013-01-22 09:00:00
3    action   a   qef   561  2013-02-18 18:00:00
4    action   z  adwq  1323  2013-01-23 16:00:00
```

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = (df.groupby(['one',pd.Grouper(freq='W-MON', key='Date')])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .sort_index(axis=1))

df.columns = df.columns.date
df['Total_frequency'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print (df)
          2013-01-21  2013-01-28  2013-02-18  Total_frequency
one                                                          
action             0           1           1                2
comedy             1           1           0                2
romantic           0           1           0                1
```

EDIT: Create boolean mask for values after first `NaN`s and replace missing values only by this mask:

```
print (df)
          2013-01-00  2013-01-07  2013-01-14
ones                                        
comedy           4.0           5         6.0
romantic         1.0           2         NaN
action           NaN           1         NaN

mask = df.notnull().cumsum(axis=1).ne(0)
#another solution
#mask = df.ffill(axis=1).notnull()

df = df.mask(mask, df.fillna(0))
print (df)
          2013-01-00  2013-01-07  2013-01-14
ones                                        
comedy           4.0           5         6.0
romantic         1.0           2         0.0
action           NaN           1         0.0
```

Comment: `Date` column must have different datetime and Years not only 2013!

Comment: @pygo - Yes, I change sample for easy verifying solution, unfortunately not possible with OP sample data.

Comment: Okay, thats sounds a deal.

Comment: @momojoh1 - So if change `.unstack(fill_value=0)` to `.unstack()` then get `NaN`s instead `0`, so if use `df.mean(axis=1)` it count mean only by non NaNs values.

Comment: Yes, then use `df = df.fillna(0)`

Comment: @momojoh1 - Not understand, sorry.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, one more question. If I wanted the columns to be the 24 hours of the day and group all hours from every date would it be possible? Thanks

Comment: @momojoh1 - Yes, change `freq='W-MON'` to `freq='D'`

Comment: @jezrael That just gives me each day for all of the dates. I was referring to just having 24 columns, each representing each hour of the day. And grouping all values under the respective hour, regardless of the date or year.

Comment: @jezrael In this case the columns would be 00:00, 01:00....22:00, 23:00. Is that possible?

Comment: @momojoh1 So change `pd.Grouper(freq='W-MON', key='Date')` to `df['Date']. dt. time`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [random.choice(['comedy', 'action', 'romantic']) for i in range(1000)],
                  'Date': pd.date_range(start = '2013-01-01', periods = 1000)})
df.head()

      one        Date
0   romantic    2013-01-01
1   romantic    2013-01-02
2   romantic    2013-01-03
3   action       2013-01-04
4   romantic    2013-01-05

df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq = 'W'), 'one'])['one'].count().unstack(level = 0)

Date          2013-01-06  2013-01-13  2013-01-20.....
one           
comedy         2         2           2              
romantic       NaN       2           2               
action         4         3           3
```